# How to get more than one record using SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

Here is my web method I want to add all the meetings in my `allmeeting` list then I want to return it and receive through kendo grid

```
List<DefMeetingDTO> AllDefCompany = new List<DefMeetingDTO>();
List<DefMeetingDTO> f = new List<DefMeetingDTO>();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    DefMeetingDTO d = new DefMeetingDTO();
    int ji = reader.FieldCount;

    do
    {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
              //for(int i = 0 ; i < ji ; i++) {
              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("md_id")))
              {
                   d.md_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["md_id"]) as int? ?? default(int);
              }
              else
              {
                   d.md_id = 0;
              }

              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("md_visitor_name")))
              {
                   d.md_visitor_name = (string)(reader["md_visitor_name"]);// as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
              }
              else
              {
                   // d.m_datetime = null;
              }

              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("md_visitor_cell")))
              {
                   d.md_visitor_cell = (reader["md_visitor_cell"]).ToString();// as string? ?? default(string);
              }

              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("md_visitor_company")))
              {
                   d.md_visitor_company = (string)reader["md_visitor_company"];
              }

              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("purpose_name")))
              {
                   d.purpose_name = (string)reader["purpose_name"];
              }

              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("m_datetime")))
              {
                   d.m_datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["m_datetime"]) as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
              }

              AllDefCompany.Add(d);
          }
     }

     while(reader.NextResult());                        
}
```

My SQL query return result as checked 4 rows

```
   10878    |   Wasim Riaz  | 0300449436     | Jade | N/A   | NULL
   71123    |   bb          | +9232531256    | F    | mee   | 2015-09-03
   71124    |   CC          | +923218531256  | Fb   | N/A   | 2015-09-03
   71125    |   DD          | +923218531256  | Gb   | N/A   | 2015-09-03
```

But the `SqlDataReader` iterates every time to 1st row only and does not go to the second to add in `allmeetinglist()` and connection times out

Comment: move `DefMeetingDTO d = new DefMeetingDTO();` to the inner loop

Comment: any purpose for using **reader.NextResult()**.are you executing two queries?

Comment: no only 1 query but reader runs only 1 time then goes out and then runs again and return 1st record 10times then connection times out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using `Do-While` loop. You can simply use a `While` loop like this:-

```
List<DefMeetingDTO>   AllDefCompany = new List<DefMeetingDTO>();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    DefMeetingDTO d = new DefMeetingDTO();
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("md_id")))
    {
          d.md_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["md_id"]) as int? ?? default(int);
    }
    else
    {
          d.md_id = 0;
    }
    AllDefCompany.Add(d);
}
```

Please note, [Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) will anyways advance the datareader to next record, so no point doing it again with `NextResult`. Also, note it is not necessary to check `reader.HasRows` since `Read` will return false if there are no more rows to fetch.

Comment: but same problem reader after reading first record moves out to _if(reader.hasrows)_  then again runs and instead of secod returns first record again

Comment: @office302 - Are you still doing that inside a `do` loop? Remove it completly it's not required. Also, HasRows is not required.

Comment: i removed moth of them but still my while statement not going to next record

Answer (score 0):

I think you are executing ** batch Transact-SQL statements** on datareader.try the below code

```
  do
    {
       if (reader.HasRows)
         {
             while (reader.Read())
            {
               DefMeetingDTO d = new DefMeetingDTO();
              if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("md_id")))
              {
                   d.md_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["md_id"]) as int? ?? default(int);
              }
              else
              {
                   d.md_id = 0;
              }
              AllDefCompany.Add(d);
           }
        }
  }
 while(reader.NextResult());
```

Comment: SELECT d.md_id , d.md_visitor_name , d.md_visitor_cell, d.md_visitor_company , p.purpose_name , m.m_datetime FROM  Vms_Meeting M left outer join  Vms_MeetingD  d  on m.M_ID= d.M_ID left outer join  Vms_Purpose p  on  m.Purpose_ID= p.purpose_id  WHERE  d.M_status='0' and m.host_id = 210 ;
with cmd.executereader

Comment: Then there is no need to use reader.nextResult.it is needed only for batch sql statements where reader will fetch more than one result.go with @Rahul Singh's answer

Comment: but problem is still instead of going to next record and iterating reader moves out and then come back to while statement and hence iterate only through **first record**

Comment: moves out means?where the control will go?try to debug

Comment: he put down because nothing was change like removing do and while and if and get set acessor _dtoclass_ to declare inside was already defined in comment first

Comment: rahul singh answer defined all things thanx